# Pointing to a variable of my choice in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do the following:

```
bool Has_Unique_Index<T>(Indexed<T> obj)
{
    byte type = Verify_Type<T>(obj);
    List<Indexed<T>> list;

    switch (type)
    {
        case 0: list = DataSource.Clients; break;
        case 1: list = DataSource.Rentals; break;
        case 2: list = DataSource.Cars;    break;
        case 3: list = DataSource.Faults;  break;
    }

    foreach (var i in list)
    {
        if (i.Index == obj.Index)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

(Couldn't figure out how use triangle brackets without them disappearing into the HTML void):

However, the compiler tells me it can't convert any of the DataSource.x to a List(Indexed(T)) type.

The Verify_Type(T)(obj) makes sure that T is one of the 4 options in the switch so List(Indexed(T))  should be fine - except it's not a pointer or anything of the sort.

- How can I point to a variable of my choice in C# using a switch statement (or any other method)?

EDIT: The DataSource.x's are of type List(Indexed(T)).

EDIT2: As people pointed out, I actually meant that the sources are of type List(Indexed(SOMECONCRETETYPE)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the properties. I'd do it only once like this:

```
bool Has_Unique_Index<T>(Indexed<T> obj)
{
    byte type = Verify_Type<T>(obj);
    object dataSource = null;

    switch (type)
    {
        case 0: dataSource = DataSource.Clients; break;
        case 1: dataSource = DataSource.Rentals; break;
        case 2: dataSource = DataSource.Cars;    break;
        case 3: dataSource = DataSource.Faults;  break;
        default: return false; // or throw an exception etc.
    }

    bool result = (dataSource as List<Indexed<T>>).Any(x => x.Index == obj.Index);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: New accepted answer since I dislike writing the same condition over and over - this feels more elegant.
Still, JesseJames' answer managed to kill a variable :)

Comment: OP If you like killing variables note that you don't _need_ `type` either. You can do `switch (Verify_Type<T>(obj))` :)

Comment: @StephenKennedy reducing too many variables is also not the best practice... sooner or later you'll need them back while debugging ;-) that's why I created the `result` helper variable.

Comment: @t3chb0t OP and I don't worry about debugging as our code always works first time, every time ;). I jest. It's just a bit of shorten the code fun.

While we're at it, `result` isn't strictly speaking necessary either, you can just return from the preceding line.

Comment: @StephenKennedy Thanks, won't be doing that, tho, since it's more readable as switch(type).

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve compilation error by explicitly casting to `(List<Index<T>>)` as `Jan Zahradník` said.

```
case 0: list = (List<Index<T>>)DataSource.Clients.ToList(); break;
```

Or simplify method:

```
bool Has_Unique_Index<T>(Indexed<T> obj)
{
    byte type = Verify_Type<T>(obj);

    switch (type)
    {
        case 0: return !DataSource.Clients.Any(r=> r.Index == obj.Index); break;
        case 1: return !DataSource.Rentals.Any(r=> r.Index == obj.Index); break;
        case 2: return !DataSource.Cars.Any(r=> r.Index == obj.Index);    break;
        case 3: return !DataSource.Faults.Any(r=> r.Index == obj.Index);  break;
    }

    throw new Exception("unknown type: " + type);
}
```

Comment: Casting doesn't seem to work, and the deleted post here had a slightly more readable solution which only had me create 'list' as an object and cast it later into a List(Indexed(T)), but this solution eliminates the extra object altogether, kudos.

One more thing, the Verify_Type already throws an exception when the type given to Has_Unique_Index is invalid.
Should I comment about it in the code to make it clear?

Comment: @user2962533 I guess you mean my answer? Hit delete indead of edit :-)

Comment: those `break` statements are unnecessary and will cause a compiler warning

Answer (score 1):

As T is generic type, i guess you don't have DataSource.Cars of type `List<Indexed<T>>`, but `List<Indexed<Car>>`. Which of course can't be casted to T in case T is eg. Client. Let's try to add explicit cast to `List<Indexed<T>>` to each list assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why compilation fails is the same reason that your edit in the question is slightly incorrect. You state that the `DataSource.x` objects are of type `List<Indexed<T>>` but in fact they are of type `List<Indexed<SOMECONCRETETYPE>>`.

Compilation fails because at least three of the `DataSource.x` objects are *not* of the *target* type of `T` (i.e. they are not generic; they have varying underlying types which are already concrete).

You can 'cast' to `List<Indexed<T>>`:

```
bool Has_Unique_Index<T>(Indexed<T> obj)
{
    List<Indexed<T>> list == null;

    switch (Verify_Type<T>(obj))
    {
        case 0: list = DataSource.Clients as List<Indexed<T>>; break;
        case 1: list = DataSource.Rentals as List<Indexed<T>>; break;
        case 2: list = DataSource.Cars as List<Indexed<T>>;    break;
        case 3: list = DataSource.Faults as List<Indexed<T>>;  break;
    }
```

MSDN: "The [as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion isn't possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception."

Throw if list is null (type was out of range or `as` returned null):

```
    if (list == null)
         throw SomeException();
```

We can use [IEnumerable.All](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a `foreach` loop:

```
    return list.All(i => i.Index != obj.Index);
}
```

Of course you can choose the shorter code in Jesse James' answer which avoids a cast/conversion altogether.